# Represent Plot Scale with an offset

Tags: graphics3d

I want to know how to represent the axis on my 3dplot with a scaled offset. Please see the image below, I just want to show in the plot as {X-Axis*0.1} and {Y-Axis*0.1} ...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ScallingTransform

e.g. the following code will scale x axis from {1,10} -> {0.1,1} by a factor 0.1

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
Show[Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[g[[1]], ScalingTransform[{0.1, 1, 1}]]], Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to just change the label itself? by using your own ticks function.

compare:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

with

```
ticks[min_, max_] := 
  Table[ { i, Style[0.1*i, 12], {.04, 0}},  {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max]}];

Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Ticks -> ticks, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html for more information

Comment: In some cases its simple to just change the data.. Plot3D[0.1 Sin[(10 x) (10 y)], {x, 0, .4}, {y, 0, .4}, Mesh -> None]  should achieve the same..  Of course its often not so simple..

Comment: I tried the method said above by Nasser, how ever I cant get it ... Please check https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0Byj8JxXAeyj_MGdXTXUwWHpwLU0/edit?usp=sharing .... Run the mathematica file and see the plot below. Since my data is huge and therefore the above method gives me too many tick marks on the plot and the calculation is time consuming ... @Abhi

Comment: You have to download the whole folder stackexchange_2/1 to run the mathematica.

Comment: IT might be simpler for you to explicitly put in the ticks you want.  Ticks->{{{0,0},{50,5},{100,10},{{0,0},{100,10}},{{400000,40000},{500000,50000}}}  Lookup Ticks[] in the manual if you dont understand